# MongoDB shell: for loop pauses for no apparent reason

Tags: javascript, mongodb, shell

I am running a script to delete duplicates in my MongoDB. It is not trivial because there is a large amount of duplicates (millions) in each collection.

duplicates in the script below is simply a list of ids of documents to be deleted (which I constructed).

The strange behavior I am observing is that sometimes MongoDB shell will stop running and pause. I notice this by keeping track of the CPU usage of the process, it will suddenly drop to 0 from time to time.

If I then press ENTER in the shell, it resumes. 
I have no idea what is causing this but it is a problem for me if I want to automate this operation. Does anyone know what might be behind this?

Thanks!

```html
  var i,j,tempDuplicates,chunk = 1000;
  for (i=0,j=duplicates.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
      print( "Deleted " + i.toString() + " records from "+ collname)
      tempDuplicates = duplicates.slice(i,i+chunk);
      // Flatten the array using reduce js function
      tempDuplicates = tempDuplicates.reduce(function(a,b){ return a.concat(b); }); 
      // Remove elements in tempDuplicates
      db[collname].remove({_id:{$in:tempDuplicates}})
  }
```

Comment: the mongo shell might be doing some processing when it pauses. You need to check what's happening behind the scene using mongostat

Comment: If you are actually processing "millions" here then your procedure here could do with some redesign. As a general guide you should be using [Bulk Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/js-bulk/), with a preference to the abstracted method [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) in modern API's. The other clear things is that you appear to be using a declared array `duplicates`, which means even though you're processing is working though that per 1000, you still have the whole array in memory. Which is not optimal.